# BigQuery client with multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, google-bigquery, python-multiprocessing

From google [docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html#:%7E:text=Because%20the%20BigQuery%20client%20uses,to%20share%20instances%20across%20threads.):

> Because the BigQuery client uses the third-party requests library by
> default and the BigQuery-Storage client uses grpcio library, both are
> safe to share instances across threads. In multiprocessing scenarios,
> the best practice is to create client instances **after**
> `multiprocessing.Pool` or `multiprocessing.Process` invokes `os.fork()`.

On the one hand "safe to share instances across threads" is mentioned, on the other, to create client instances after "os.fork()" is done.
And I don't understand if I can create one client and pass to threads to use, or if each thread has to initialize client itself separately.

I realize multithreading with the following code:

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES) as proc:
    proc.map(my_bq_func, arguments_list)
```

Comment: Its better to create a new client in every process. Its hard to share the same client across processes anyway; you have to use Manager etc.